# SQL to retrieve side by side results

Tags: sql

I have some tables arranged like this sudo code.

```
table event {
  id
  field_1
}

table event_link {
  id
  start_event_id
  end_event_id
}
```

I wan't to display the linked "event's" side by side in one query kind of like this.

start_id, start_field_1, end_id, end_field_1

I'm really struggling with the SQL. This is what I have so far.

```
select start_event.id as start_id, start_event.field_1 as start_field_1, end_event.id as end_id, end_event.field_1 as end_field_1 from
 (
   select id, field_1 from event inner join
    (
      select start_event_id from event_link
    ) on event.id = event_link.start_event_id
 ) as start_event,
 (
   select id, field_1 from event inner join
    (
      select end_event_id from event_link
    ) on event.id = event_link.end_event_id
 ) as end_event;
```

This query does not work for me but it's as close I can get. What do I need to do to get the results I need?

Answer (score 0):

Use two joins:

```
select es.*, ee.*
from event_link el join
     event es
     on el.start_event_id = es.id join
     event ee
     on el.end_event_id = el.id
```